# Kruskals Algorithm using C

Tags: c, algorithm

I have two Kruskal algorithm implementations. One which I made and another one which I took from a friend. Both programs look almost same to me, except for a few things that do not matter.

His program is giving a  different output than mine, though I think both of them are giving the wrong set of edges but the right weight.

My program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct info
{
    int initial;
    int final;
    int weight;
}info;

void uon(int x,int y,int*p,int *r);
int findset(int x,int *p);
void sort(info *edgelist,int n);
void qksort(info *edgelist,int l,int u);
int partition(info *edgelist,int l,int u);
void makeset(int n,int *p,int *r);
int kruskal(info *edgelist,int n,int w);

int main()
{

    FILE *fp;
    int n,i,j,temp;
    int **gmatrix,cost;
    info *edgelist;
    int cnt =0,a;
    fp = fopen("grph.txt","r");

    fscanf(fp,"%d",&n);

    gmatrix=(int**)calloc(sizeof(int*),n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        gmatrix[i]=(int*)calloc(sizeof(int),n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d",&temp);
            gmatrix[i][j]=temp;
        }
    }

    edgelist = (info*)calloc(sizeof(info),n*n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d  ",gmatrix[i][j]);
            temp = gmatrix[i][j];
            a=cnt;
            if(temp !=0)
            {
                edgelist[a].initial = i;
                edgelist[a].weight = temp;
                edgelist[a].final = j;
                cnt++;
            }

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%d \n",edgelist[0].initial);
    printf("%d \n ",cnt);

    cost =kruskal(edgelist,n,cnt);
    printf("\nTotal Cost is %d",cost);

    return 0;
}

int kruskal(info *edgelist,int n,int cnt)
{
    int b,i,initial,dest,cost_cnt=0;
    int *p,*r;
    int cost=0;
    info *krus;

    p = (int*)calloc(sizeof(int),n);
    r = (int*)calloc(sizeof(int),n);

    makeset(n,p,r);
    qksort(edgelist,0,cnt);
    //sort(edgelist,w);

    krus=(info*)calloc(sizeof(info),n-1);
    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
    {
        //printf("INITIAL 1 : %d \n",edgelist[i].initial);
        initial=findset(edgelist[i].initial,p);
    //  printf("INITIAL 2 : %d \n",initial);
        dest=findset(edgelist[i].final,p);

        if(initial!=dest)
        {
            b=cost_cnt; 
            krus[b].initial=initial;
            krus[b].final=dest;
            krus[b].weight=edgelist[i].weight;
            cost_cnt++;
            uon(initial,dest,p,r);
        }

    }
        for(i=0;i<cost_cnt;i++)
        {
            printf("{%d,%d}: %d \n",krus[i].initial+1,krus[i].final+1, krus[i].weight);
            cost = cost + krus[i].weight;
        }
    return cost;

}

void uon(int initial,int dest,int *p,int *r)
{
    int u,v;
    //link(findset(x),findset(y));
    printf("\n X1 : %d",initial);
    u = findset(initial,p);
    printf("\n X2 : %d",initial);
    v = findset(dest,p);
    if(r[u]>r[v])
    {
        p[v] = u;
    }
    else
    {
        p[u] = v;

        if(r[u]==r[v])
            r[v] = r[v]+1;
    }
}


int findset(int x,int *p)
{
    if(x!=p[x])
    {

        p[x]=findset(p[x],p);
    }
    return p[x];
}
void makeset(int n,int *p,int *r)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p[i] = i;
        r[i] = 0;
    }
}



void qksort(info *edgelist,int l,int u) {
    int pq;
    if(l<u) 
    {
        pq=partition(edgelist,l,u);
        qksort(edgelist,l,pq-1);
        qksort(edgelist,pq+1,u);
    }
}

int partition(info *edgelist,int l,int u) {
    int i,j,pq;
    info pv,t;
    pv.initial=edgelist[l].initial;
    pv.final=edgelist[l].final;
    pv.weight=edgelist[l].weight;
    j=l;
    for(i=l+1;i<=u;i++)
    {
        if(edgelist[i].weight<=pv.weight) 
        {
            j++;
            t=edgelist[i];

            t.initial=edgelist[i].initial;
            t.final=edgelist[i].final;
            t.weight=edgelist[i].weight;

            edgelist[i].initial=edgelist[j].initial;
            edgelist[i].final=edgelist[j].final;
            edgelist[i].weight=edgelist[j].weight;

            edgelist[j].initial=t.initial;
            edgelist[j].final=t.final;
            edgelist[j].weight=t.weight;
        }
    }
    pq=j;

    t.initial=edgelist[pq].initial;
    t.final=edgelist[pq].final;
    t.weight=edgelist[pq].weight;

    edgelist[pq].initial=edgelist[l].initial;
    edgelist[pq].final=edgelist[l].final;
    edgelist[pq].weight=edgelist[l].weight;

    edgelist[l].initial=t.initial;
    edgelist[l].final=t.final;
    edgelist[l].weight=t.weight;

    return(pq);
}
```

Friends Program :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct info{
    int initial;
    int dest;
    int weight;
};
void kruskal(struct info *,int **,int,int);
void makeset(int *,int *,int);
void quick_sort(struct info *,int,int);
int find_set(int *,int);
void union_set(int * ,int *,int,int);
int partition(struct info *,int,int);

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int **gmatrix;
    int num,source,i,j,temp,count,a;
    struct info *edgelist;
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("enter the proper argument");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&num);
    printf("num=%d\n",num);
    gmatrix=(int **)calloc(sizeof(int *),num);

    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
        gmatrix[i]=(int *)calloc(sizeof(int),num);

    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<num;j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d",&temp);
            *(*(gmatrix+i)+j)=temp;
        }
    }
    edgelist=(struct info *)calloc(sizeof(struct info),num*num);

    count=0;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<num;j++)
        {
            temp=*(*(gmatrix+i)+j);
            if(temp!=0)
            {

                a=count;            
                edgelist[a].initial=i;
                edgelist[a].dest=j;
                printf("(%d,%d)\n",edgelist[a].initial,edgelist[a].dest);
                edgelist[a].weight=temp;
                printf("weight=%d\t",edgelist[a].weight);

                count=count+1;
                printf("a=%d\n",count);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("ans=%d\t",count);
    kruskal(edgelist,gmatrix,num,count);
}

void kruskal(struct info *edgelist,int **gmatrix,int num,int count)
{

    int *parent;
    int *rank;
    int i,cost_count,b,initial,dest,cost=0;
    struct info *krus;  
    parent = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int),num);
    rank   = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int),num);

    makeset(parent,rank,num);
    quick_sort(edgelist,0,count);
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        printf("sorting=%d\t",edgelist[i].weight);
    }

    krus=(struct info *)calloc(sizeof(struct info),num-1);
    cost_count=0;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        initial=find_set(parent,edgelist[i].initial);
        dest=find_set(parent,edgelist[i].dest);

        if(initial != dest )
        {
            b=cost_count;
            krus[b].initial=initial;
            krus[b].dest=dest;
            krus[b].weight=edgelist[i].weight;
            cost_count=cost_count+1;
    //      printf("weight=%d and (%d,%d)\t",krus[b].weight,krus[b].initial,krus[b].dest);
            union_set(parent,rank,initial,dest);
        }

    }

        for (i=0;i<num-1;i++) {
        printf("\n%d . {%d, %d}",i+1,krus[i].initial+1,krus[i].dest+1);
        cost = cost + krus[i].weight;
        }

    printf("\ncost of minimum mst is..... %d\n\n",cost);

}



void union_set(int *parent ,int *rank,int initial,int dest)
{
    int u,v;
    printf("\n X1 : %d",u);
    u=find_set(parent,initial);
    printf("\n X2 : %d\n",u);
    v=find_set(parent,dest);
    if(rank[u]>rank[v])
        parent[v]=u;
    else    
    {
        parent[u]=v;
        if(rank[u]==rank[v])
        rank[v]=rank[v]+1;
    }
}
int find_set(int *parent,int x)
{
    if(x!=parent[x])
        parent[x] = find_set(parent,parent[x]);
    return parent[x];
}
void makeset(int *parent,int *rank,int num)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) 
    {
        parent[i] = i;
        rank[i]   = 0;
    }
}
void quick_sort(struct info *edgelist,int left,int right)
{
    int q;
    if(left<right)
    {
        q=partition(edgelist,left,right);
        quick_sort(edgelist,left,q-1);
        quick_sort(edgelist,q+1,right);
    }
}
int partition(struct info *edgelist,int left,int right)
{
    struct info pivot,temp;
    int i,j,k,pp;

    pivot.initial=edgelist[left].initial;
    pivot.dest   =edgelist[left].dest;
    pivot.weight =edgelist[left].weight;

    j=left;


    for(i=left+1;i<=right;i++)
    {
        if(edgelist[i].weight < pivot.weight)
        {
        j=j+1;

        temp.initial=edgelist[i].initial;
        temp.dest=edgelist[i].dest;
        temp.weight=edgelist[i].weight;

        edgelist[i].initial=edgelist[j].initial;
        edgelist[i].dest=edgelist[j].dest;
        edgelist[i].weight=edgelist[j].weight;

        edgelist[j].initial=temp.initial;
        edgelist[j].dest=temp.dest;
        edgelist[j].weight=temp.weight;
        }
    }
    pp=j;

    temp.initial=edgelist[left].initial;
    temp.dest=edgelist[left].dest;
    temp.weight=edgelist[left].weight;

    edgelist[left].initial=edgelist[pp].initial;
    edgelist[left].dest=edgelist[pp].dest;
    edgelist[left].weight=edgelist[pp].weight;

    edgelist[pp].initial=temp.initial;
    edgelist[pp].dest=temp.dest;
    edgelist[pp].weight=temp.weight;

        //printf("aaaa=%d\t\n",pp);

    return pp;
}
```

The graph I am using:

```
9
0 4 0 0 0 0 0 8 0
4 0 8 0 0 0 0 11 0
0 8 0 7 0 4 0 0 2
0 0 7 0 9 14 0 0 0
0 0 0 9 0 10 0 0 0
0 0 4 14 10 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 6
8 11 0 0 0 0 1 0 7
0 0 2 0 0 0 6 7 0
```

The weight is 37 but the programs aren't giving the correct set of edges.

Comment: That's a whole lot of code you've posted, and it's unlikely that many users will read through it all.  What differences have you identified so far?  Which ones matter?  Which ones don't?

Comment: This is definitely a lot of code. One thing that caught my attention (it is probably not the only problem or even the main one) is the inconsistent use of `calloc`: the first argument should be the number of elements, the last is the element's size. This can affect how the memory is allocated and nulled. Usually the presence of such errors are an indication that there are other inconsistencies in your code.

Comment: Kruskals Algorithm is a well known problem. I suggest you find an already implemented version of the algorithm and use that. Your asking for code review, which belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Find a much simpler input graph that also causes your problem. Then debug the code to see where it goes wrong. Do the algorithm on paper first if necessary – or use the [example on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_Algorithm#Example).

Comment: Obviously at least one of the things that "do not matter" ... do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sorting order

The difference between the codes are that in the quick sort routine one code uses:

```
if(edgelist[i].weight<=pv.weight)
```

while the other uses

```
if(edgelist[i].weight < pivot.weight)
```

This results in different orders of presentation of the edges.

Both solutions are calculating valid but different minimal spanning trees.

### Edge display

However, the final of display of the chosen edges is incorrect in both solutions because of the code:

```
krus[b].initial=initial;
krus[b].final=dest;
```

which stores the initial and dest variables *after* they have been passed through the findset routine.  This should be replaced with:

```
krus[b].initial=edgelist[i].initial
krus[b].final=edgelist[i].final
```

### P.S.

By the way, both solutions also share the bug of calling

```
 qksort(edgelist,0,cnt);
```

instead of

```
 qksort(edgelist,0,cnt-1);
```

but this does not make any difference to the output.  (All that happens is that the first presented edge looks like it starts and ends at 0 so is ignored.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked at the algorithm and the program repeatedly and found was thinking the same thing about the assignment of to the solution graph. It didn't seem right. And what you said over here confirmed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the printed weights don't correspond to the node numbers, so if parsing and printing are OK, then the node info is corrupted somewhere.

The quicksort implementation seems fine, and the only other place that modifies node info is the `kruskal()` function.

So, hint: double-check the assignment to `krus[b].initial`. Is `initial` really the initial node number for edge `i`?